# Does it matter if I use the word "obligatorisch" or "zwingend" for compulsory?

Tags: single-word-request

I want to say "it is not compulsory for children between the ages of 3 and 6 to go to kindergarten". Would it be "Es ist für Kinder im Alter von 3 bis 6 nicht obligatorisch (oder zwingend) in den Kindergarten gehen? Does it matter what word I use?

Comment: Frankly, both sound slightly unidiomatic in this context. I'd go with _verpflichtend_, or even rewrite the sentence using " ... müssen nicht ..."

Comment: I try to restrict my use of _obligatorisch_ (and _fakultativ_) to Academese. Another similar word is _vorgeschrieben_.

Comment: „... **zu** gehen“

Answer (score 7):

Yet, it matters. There is a difference in tone and thus in meaning.

If you have to decide between those two choices, you’d probably go with *obligatorisch*, because it’s close to “mandatory”. It may be interpreted as “bound by duty”. With a slightly stricter connotation, *zwingend* might sound to much like compulsion or even enforcement.

If you’re not under constraint regarding your choice of words, you have various alternatives, like *erforderlich* (“required to”) or *verpflichtend* (“compulsory”, rather duty than constraint) or *notwendig* (“necessary”) or *bindend* (“binding”).

Note that you’ll find corresponding translations for all of these words due to their related meaning. It depends on context how it’s interpreted.

Comment: @user19770: Gladly. I just hope it didn’t create too much confusion showing *some* of the alternatives.